# Accessing Multiple Services/Methods through a Single WCF End Point

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, web-services, interface

And thanks for taking the time for reading this. I'm a little new to working with WCF and came across and issue that I'm unsure how to deal with.

I have a AJAX web service accessible through a single WCF end point. I have a large system who's methods are all segmented by functionality. What I want to know is does anyone know a way I can access all my methods even if they are located in different classes?

What I'm trying to avoid is having a single class that contains a ton of web methods or having to write an interface layer to handle delegating the method to the proper class. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks! (C#)

Answer (score 1):

You could try WCF routing service. The Routing service can acts as a single mediator between two or more services.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500646.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423.aspx

http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2011/8/routing_service_and_content_based_routing